How to export a docx to a pdf but keeping the current zoom value?
For any .docx file opened through MS Word (Office 365). If it has a specific zoom such as 130%.
Question

How to export a docx to a pdf but keeping the current zoom value?

Therefore in any place where a PDF editor opens the .pdf file (generated from the mentioned .docx file) it must show the document with the zoom 130% value.
Is possible do this? How?
Examples
For a better explanation consider the following:
aaa.docx (edited and saved with zoom 130%)
 Export to aaa.pdf
  Opened with already zoom 130%

bbb.docx (edited and saved with zoom 150%)
 Export to bbb.pdf
  Opened with already zoom 150%

Therefore the .pdf file itself must inherit the original zoom applied in the .docx file

This is a broken concept to me (and would annoy me greatly, just like full screen on open, etc...) - it may be technically possible to set a desired "initial zoom" that is used by some viewers, but not all viewers are going to obey. Why do you need (or even want) the PDF to be "pre-zoomed"?

Hello to all: It is a requirement: it to solve a scenario about to use a specific zoom for 3 types of docx files. Thus each docx file requires a different zoom value. Thus is important avoid for the final user be changing a lot of times (even by mistake) the zoom types according the docx file category.

Create the PDF as usual and open it in Acrobat
Go to document properties (Control-D)
Go to the "Initial View" tab
For magnification, type 130%
edit: you may need the Pro version of Acrobat to do this

You can run
cpdf -open-at-page-custom "[1 /XYZ null null 1.3]" in.pdf -o out.pdf
1 = first page, 1.3 = 130% zoom.
Up to the PDF reader whether they honour it, though.

Zoom on open a PDF is set by many factors.

The optional zoom value on file open, may be added into the PDF and be used or ignored by the viewer.
Here the PDF contains the /OpenAction of go to the page described in object 5  and zoom XYZ whole page to ratio 1.3 (130%).

/OpenAction <</D [5 0 R /XYZ null null 1.3]/S /GoTo>>

The client may also set an optional zoom over-ride value as part of the viewer setting itself. So all files start at the same zoom value, regardless of what the internal setting is. This is useful for those users needing Large Print Accessibility. But would be annoying to those that do not want such controls.


Clearly it depends on the user and their choice of viewer.
Acrobat desktop will respect such control if user allows it.
However Browsers may not be able to zoom on demand.

Chromium's usually default to 100%.
Firefox may try to match nearest default of 125%.
Acrobat should respect 1.30 if not over-ridden.
Other desktop/Web viewers may be set to start all files @ 130% (by user preference).


